# Migration of NSSQLite to Seam3 storage type fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm still trying to setup proper migration of existing NSSQLiteStore to SMStore.Type ([Seam3](https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3)) and getting strange issue. Cannot understand why it happens. I have raised [the same for Paul on github](https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3/issues/56), but probably somebody will noticed the cause in my code and will be able to help, while Paul is busy.

What do I have:
App running on iOS 10+ with NSSQLiteStore located in default folder.

Steps of testing:

1. Remove new store (if exists) and it's supporting files located in new path:
   file:///Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3708F142-3BD0-4C70-8515-217B7785D285/data/Containers/Data/Application/29B60BBC-0D17-4D6C-8107-0135C45B20BA/Documents/CafeManagerSeam3.sqlite
2. Run app. App should check if new store exists. If not - perform migration from default one.
3. App tries to migrate store and fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
   But in the same time I can see that new store appeared in new path and if I run app once again, it uses new store with no visible issues.

[image]

My code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var smStore: SMStore?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let storeDescriptionType = AppDelegate.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first?.type
            if storeDescriptionType == SMStore.type {
                print("Store is SMStore")
                print()
                self.smStore = AppDelegate.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first as? SMStore
            }
        } else {
            let storeDescriptionType = AppDelegate.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores.first?.type
            if storeDescriptionType == SMStore.type {
                print("Store is SMStore")
                print()
                self.smStore = AppDelegate.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores.first as? SMStore
            }
        }
...
    // MARK: - Core Data stack for iOS 10+
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CafeManager")
        let persistentStoreCoordinator = container.persistentStoreCoordinator

        //MARK: Initializing Seam3
        SMStore.registerStoreClass()
        SMStore.syncAutomatically = true

        //MARK: Preparing URL
        let applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            return urls[urls.count-1]
        }()
        let newURL = applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("CafeManagerSeam3.sqlite")

        //MARK: Check if SQLite store has been already migrated by checking if CafeManagerSeam3.sqlite exists.
        let seamStoreExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: newURL.path)

        if seamStoreExists {
            //If exists, then use it because it has been already migrated to Seam3 storage
            print("Already migrated, using \(newURL)")

            let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: newURL)
            storeDescription.type = SMStore.type
            storeDescription.setOption("iCloud.iGlock.CafeManager.com" as NSString, forKey: SMStore.SMStoreContainerOption)
            storeDescription.setOption(NSNumber(value:SMSyncConflictResolutionPolicy.clientTellsWhichWins.rawValue), forKey:SMStore.SMStoreSyncConflictResolutionPolicyOption)
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions=[storeDescription]

            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            return container

        } else {
            //If does not exist, then migrate old storage to Seam3.
            print("Not yet migrated, migrating to \(newURL)")

            //Loadig default store
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Failed to load default store \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            let defaultPersistentStore = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last
            print("Default store is located here: \(defaultPersistentStore!.url!)")

            //Adding new Seam3 store
            do {
                try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: SMStore.type, configurationName: nil, at: newURL, options: nil)
                print("Seam store was added to the new url: \(newURL)")
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failed to add new Seam store: \(error)")
            }

            //Migrating default store to new Seam store
            do {
                try persistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(defaultPersistentStore!, to: newURL, options: nil, withType:SMStore.type)
                //Removing old store
                if defaultPersistentStore != nil {
                    do {
                        try persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(defaultPersistentStore!)
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failed to remove default store \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                fatalError("Failed to migrate to Seam store: \(error)")
            }

            //Setting additional parameters to Seam store to make it able to use CloudKit
            let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: newURL)
            storeDescription.type = SMStore.type
            storeDescription.setOption("iCloud.iGlock.CafeManager.com" as NSString, forKey: SMStore.SMStoreContainerOption)
            storeDescription.setOption(NSNumber(value:SMSyncConflictResolutionPolicy.clientTellsWhichWins.rawValue), forKey:SMStore.SMStoreSyncConflictResolutionPolicyOption)
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions=[storeDescription]

            return container
        }
```

Output:

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3708F142-3BD0-4C70-8515-217B7785D285/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3E4EB624-227E-4BD0-99F1-AA975D86BDA8/CafeManager.app/CafeManager.momd/CafeManager v2.omo'
Not yet migrated, migrating to file:///Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3708F142-3BD0-4C70-8515-217B7785D285/data/Containers/Data/Application/100FB44C-C881-44C1-9D03-454FEBDB092B/Documents/CafeManagerSeam3.sqlite
Default store is located here: file:///Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3708F142-3BD0-4C70-8515-217B7785D285/data/Containers/Data/Application/100FB44C-C881-44C1-9D03-454FEBDB092B/Library/Application%20Support/CafeManager.sqlite
Seam store was added to the new url: file:///Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3708F142-3BD0-4C70-8515-217B7785D285/data/Containers/Data/Application/100FB44C-C881-44C1-9D03-454FEBDB092B/Documents/CafeManagerSeam3.sqlite
2017-10-31 17:49:47.762 CafeManager[52561:7472303] Access to CloudKit has not been verified by calling verifyCloudKitConnection
(lldb) po self
error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7ffee595ef80.
(lldb) 
What am I doing wrong? Is it my misunderstanding of CoreData stack or something else?
```

Output when I rerun app after it's crash:

```
objc[52621]: Class _NSZombie_OS_xpc_endpoint is implemented in both ?? (0x618000048340) and ?? (0x600000047290). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3708F142-3BD0-4C70-8515-217B7785D285/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0B098A31-C927-44C0-87C2-2F2B944DF66C/CafeManager.app/CafeManager.momd/CafeManager v2.omo'
Already migrated, using file:///Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3708F142-3BD0-4C70-8515-217B7785D285/data/Containers/Data/Application/932E6B3A-65B1-44F1-920B-DCE5F242C9C7/Documents/CafeManagerSeam3.sqlite
Store is SMStore

Sync Started
No more records coming
Sync Performed
Sync performed successfully
//some test insert that was loaded to Cloud.
Sync Started
No more records coming
Sync Performed
Sync performed successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was solved. Used [example](https://github.com/paulw11/migrateSample) from Paul.

```
{
            // If does not exist, then migrate old storage to Seam3.
            print("Not yet migrated, migrating to \(newURL)")
            SMStore.syncAutomatically = false

            // Loadig default store
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Failed to load default store \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            let defaultPersistentStore = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last
            print("Default store is located here: \(defaultPersistentStore!.url!)")

            //Migrating default store to new Seam store
            do {
                try persistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(defaultPersistentStore!, to: newURL, options: nil, withType:SMStore.type)
            }
            catch {
                fatalError("Failed to migrate to Seam store: \(error)")
            }

            //Setting additional parameters to Seam store to make it able to use CloudKit
            let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: newURL)
            storeDescription.type = SMStore.type
            storeDescription.setOption("iCloud.iGlock.CafeManager.com" as NSString, forKey: SMStore.SMStoreContainerOption)
            storeDescription.setOption(NSNumber(value:SMSyncConflictResolutionPolicy.clientTellsWhichWins.rawValue), forKey:SMStore.SMStoreSyncConflictResolutionPolicyOption)
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions=[storeDescription]
            SMStore.syncAutomatically = true
            return container
        }
```